# How to filter and search in the Nagios XI web interface?

Tags: nagios

Having been given (erroronious?) instructions on how to look at Nagios XI I was wondering the following:

If under `Service Status Summary` I click the number under `Critical`, I get a filter which states that it is only displaying critical errors, and at the top a message is displayed which reads `Filters: Service=Critical`.  This would indicate that only services on hosts that have critical errors are displayed in the resulting query.

However, next I am to use the search box to search for services with a particular string in them...this invalidates the filtering after clicking search `Filters: Service=Critical` no longer appears and the list needs to be sorted so that criticals appear at the top.

Is there a way in the web interface to both search for services of a certain string and apply a filter simultaniously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out....oddly changing the query string arguments submitted to it seems to allow for what I am requesting but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this using the user interface.

1. Login to nagios...
2. Click the `Service Status Summary` number under `Critical`
3. Click the Hamburger button
4. In the menu that appears click `Popout` (it's got an icon with a little arrow)
5. This will in turn open a new window in which you can see the query arguments submitted from that frame.
6. Within the query string for the window note the value of the `servicestatustypes` argument, it should be `16` if you are looking for `critical` service errors.
7. Run a search from the search box.
8. When the results come back up, you will have lost the `Filters: Service=Critical` (and this is the problem that I had)
9. Append an `&` to the end of the query string and add `servicestatustypes=16` and press enter.

Now you will have it both filtered by Status Critical and whatever your search was.